# Libxml2 won't validate a document with XSD, only with DTD. Why? What do the standards say?

Tags: xml, xsd, libxml2, dtd

Note, validation is a different thing than well-formedness. Well-formedness means a syntactically correct XML document.

Validity is a narrower thing: it also requires the document to pass a criteria specific the format of the document.

My research has shown that there are two standards for the XML validation: DTD and XSD. While DTD belongs to an XML document, XSD belongs to an XML tag. Obviously, it can be set up also on the root tag of an XML document, like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RootTag xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="./example.xsd">
   <!-- ... -->
</RootTag>
```

Logic would dictate that the following C++ code, reading and validating the document, should work:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  try {
    xmlpp::DomParser parser;
    parser.set_validate();
    parser.set_substitute_entities(); //We just want the text to be resolved/unescaped automatically.
    parser.parse_file("example.xml");
    ...
  }
  catch(const std::exception& ex) {
    std::cout << "Exception caught: " << ex.what() << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

However, it doesn't happen. The code faults with

```
Exception caught: 
Validity error:
File example.xml, line 2, column 111 (error):
Validation failed: no DTD found !
```

It looks to me, that libxml++ wants to somehow validate exclusively by DTD. An analog XML file, but using a DTD validator, works without any problem.

Why? Can I validate whole XML documents by XSD? This is a limitation of the libxml2, I missed something in the libxml2 documentation, or simply it is the standard?

For validating documents, I would prefer XSD, but also DTD validation is okay, if that is the standard (on some reason).

Comment: Both DTDs and XML Schema (and Relax NG) are standards for XML validation. DTDs are an optional part of W3C's core XML specification (and are a subset of SGML DTDs, on which XML is based; thus are part of ISO 8879). XML Schema and Relax NG are separate specifications by W3C and ISO, resp. libxml2 has incomplete support for XML Schema; you cam enable it by compiling libxml from source (or at least you could about ten years ago).

Comment: @imhotap libxml2 today has schema support, `xmllint --schema ... ...` works. But, if I turn on "validate" in the C++ code, it somehow still looks only for dtd.

Comment: Have a look at libxml2's [xmlschemas API](http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-xmlschemas.html). It's probably not exposed by libxml++.

Comment: @nwellnhof Tyvm the tip! We are on the track. But I've checked the libxml++ upstream and I've found [this](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/libxmlplusplus/blob/master/libxml++/validators/xsdvalidator.h). So some type of xsd validation exists in the libxml++, but why is it not bound to a `.set_validate()`? As far I understand, xsd validation happens on the tag-level, while DTD validation on the document level. But nothing forbids to bind an xsd schema to the root tag of an xml document.

Comment: I can't comment on libxml++ specifics, but with libxml2 XSD validity must be checked manually in a separate step after parsing. There's simply no parser flag like for DTD validation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to validate using a schema (XSD), you need to prepare a xmlpp::XsdValidator object and use that to validate your XML.

Example preparation of validator:

```
xmlpp::DomParser schema;
schema.parse_file("example.xsd");

xmlpp::XsdValidator validator;
validator.parse_document( schema.get_document() );
```

Example usage of validator:

```
try {
  xmlpp::DomParser parser;
  parser.parse_file("example.xml");
  validator.validate( parser.get_document() );
  // Use the validated XML...
}

catch(const xmlpp::exception &e) {
  std::cerr << "Went wrong: " << e.what() << std::endl;
}
```